# Help with Integrals (and conditional expectations) of the Beta distribution: Integrate[e^(az) z^a (1-z)^b, {z, 0, 1}]

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have a Beta distribution, and am interested in calculating expectations and conditional expectations.  The domain on the distribution is $z \in [0,1]$ Ignoring constants of proportionality, the expectation of an exponential function is:

```
$Assumptions = z >= 0 && z <= 1 && a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0 && d > 0 && d < 1;

Print["*******Different parameters, {a,b}"];
Integrate[Exp[c z]  z^(a - 1) (1 - z)^(b - 1), {z, 0, 1}]

Print["********Symmetric parameter, a"];
Integrate[Exp[c z]  z^(a - 1) (1 - z)^(b - 1) /. {b -> a}, {z, 0, 1}]
```

The output from this is:

```
Gamma[a] Gamma[b] Hypergeometric1F1Regularized[a, a + b, c]
(-c)^(1/2 - a) E^(c/2) Sqrt[\[Pi]]  BesselI[-(1/2) + a, -(c/2)] Gamma[a]
```

These are solid.  The problem I am having is when calculating conditional expectations, which is effectively integration over a subset of the domain.  Again ignoring constants of proportionality,

```
Print["********Truncated Integral on [d, 1], symmetric for simplicity"];
Integrate[Exp[c z]  z^(a - 1) (1 - z)^(b - 1) /. {b -> a}, {z, d, 1}]
```

This is unable to solve it.  Any idea on this? Are there any tricks in mathematica, in math that I am missing?

Comment: `{z, d, 1}` are you sure it is appropriate ?

Comment: for some fixed $0 \leq d < 1$, why wouldn't it be?

Comment: Integrate of a function is not from range of `R` to constant.It is from constant to constant or function to function.

Comment: I am very confused.  Isn't the following legitimate for example? `Integrate[z, {z, d, 1}]` --> `1/2 - d^2/2`

Comment: you shall try integration by parts, it shall help.`d` in assumption doesn't play any role and is considered a symbol if you place it in range part.

Comment: It does matter as d = 0 has a closed form solution in terms of special functions (see the definition of the confluent hypergeometric function, for example).  I don't think those are derived through integration by parts, but thanks for the idea.

Comment: `M` cannot integrate some of them, so IBP definitely works because you will be able to break it to small pieces.

Comment: If you can find the appropriate IBP substitution it would be appreciated, but I am pretty sure you would fail to do much on the [0,1] bounds than derive relationships between the special functions.